# How to retrieve list of all implemented versions of my api?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, api-versioning, aspnet-api-versioning

I'm using [aspnet-api-versioning](https://github.com/microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning) in my WebApi project and it works fine. Versions are not hardcoded, they are retrieved from the namespaces.

Now I would like to retrieve the list of already implemented versions. I want to create some endpoint (let's call it *GetApiVersions*) that user could call to retrieve a simple collection of existing api version numbers, e.g. [1, 2, 3].

In the code responsible for selecting a correct api version based on the retrieved request (`CurrentImplementationApiVersionSelector`, `SelectVersion` method), there is an `ApiVersionModel` parameter with the `ImplementedApiVersions` property.

The `ImplementedApiVersions` property seems to be exactly what I need, but I have no idea how to access it within my *GetApiVersions* endpoint. Is there a way to retrieve it? Or is there any other way to programmatically retrieve a list of implemented api versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to access `ImplementedApiVersions` property. I had to come up with a workaround. I've created a service (called ApiVersionService) with a static field (`List<string> ApiVersions`). Service allows to register and read registered versions. As I'm using swagger, I registered all versions in `SwaggerConfig.cs` file:

```
configuration.EnableSwagger(ApiDocConfiguration.RouteTemplate, swagger =>
{
    swagger.MultipleApiVersions(
        (apiDescription, version) => apiDescription.GetGroupName() == version,
        info =>
        {
            foreach (var group in apiExplorer.ApiDescriptions)
            {
                apiVersionService.AddApiVersion(group.Name);
                // some other code
            }
        });
});
```

Simple endpoint allows me to retrieve all versions:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("versions")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetVersions()
    {
        // apiVersionService returns the data stored in ApiVersions field
        var versions = apiVersionService.GetApiVersions();
        return Ok(versions);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

@Marta what is your goal? What do you expect to do with the API versions once you have them? That will dictate the solution.

If all you want to do is report this information back in requests, this is built-in; you need only turn it on.

```cs
options.ReportApiVersions = true;
```

This will return the **api-supported-versions** and **api-deprecated-versions** headers. You can see this and more information in the [Version Discovery](https://github.com/microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/wiki/Version-Discovery) wiki topic.

You can also use the **GetApiVersionModel** extension method on the currently executing action in your controller. Again - depending on when and where you are in the pipeline determines how you retrieve the information.

For documentation type scenarios, you want the [API Versioning API Explorer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Versioning.ApiExplorer/) package as well. That will provide an **IApiExplorer** implementation for Web API that will collate all APIs and routes by API version. You can reorder them as desired. This is the same approach/technique that Swagger/OpenAPI generators use to build their documents. You integrate it into your application via:

```cs
var apiExplorer = configuration.AddVersionedApiExplorer(options => { });

// TODO: use the API Explorer
```

Exactly how you use the API Explorer is up to you. Do note that the built-in **IApiExplorer** interface doesn't support the notion of *grouping*. If you rely purely on the interface, you'll get a flatten list. This will matter depending on where you reference the API Explorer implementation. If you request the API Explorer later in your application, you either have to work within the confines of the original **IApiExplorer** interface or cast up to **VersionedApiExplorer**. The `AddVersionedApiExplorer` extension method always returns a **VersionedApiExplorer**. You can also imperatively create and/or extend the **VersionedApiExplorer** rather than using the provided extension or `configuration.Services.GetApiExplorer()`.

You can see an example of integration [here](https://github.com/microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/blob/master/samples/webapi/SwaggerWebApiSample/Startup.cs#L37). However, if you really want to see how it's used and you're not familiar with **IApiExplorer**, then you probably want to look at a repo such as [Swashbuckle](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle).

I hope that helps. Feel free to ask more questions.

Comment: Thanks @Chris for your interest. I need to create an API enpoint that will supply our custom docs page with the list of all available versions. This list would populate a dropdown that allows selection of a documentation with specific version.

Comment: I've updated the answer based on your clarification. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use can use the following interface,  `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer.IApiVersionDescriptionProvider` and get access to `ApiVersionDescriptions`

There is list of all implemented versions!